# ImageButtons not appear on the layout

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have 2 layouts: `activity_main` and `activity_car_service`;
I created some mipmaps from where I got my images buttons source

When running the app the `activity_main` contains all my buttons but when pressing an `imageButton` to open the `activity_car_service` can not see any of them...

`activity_car_service` is declared in manifest, still not see any `imageButton`

Here is `activity_car_service`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1111"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:background="@null"
                android:onClick="sendMessage"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_auto_tracting" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2111"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_auto_lighting" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3111"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_carservice" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton34111"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_auto_oil" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_auto_brakes" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_auto_battery" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_auto_engine" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton66"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_auto_brakes" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how I call it:

```
public class CarServiceSubMenu extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_service);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="utils.CarServiceSubMenu">
    android:label = "lala"/>
</activity>
```

MainActivity:

```
public void openCarServiceSubMenu(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CarServiceSubMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

activity_main which is working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sharmind93.nj00.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:onClick="sendMessage"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_fire" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_plumbing" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:onClick="openCarServiceSubMenu"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_carservice" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton34"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_dentist" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_lightning" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_hairdress" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_carwash" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton66"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_misc" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton16"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What can be the problem ? I spent so much time to try out different things ...

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was that I used  app:srcCompat but my activity was not AppCompatActivity ....

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageButtons have width=match_parent while its parent have width=wrap_content.

Their size is 0.

Change the first LLayout with to match_parent too so you can see then.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Also,your layout will cover the button, try to use below=button (since you are using RelativeLayout as parent and height=wrap_content

The RelativeLayout can be used for adding constraint like below/onTopof/toRightof other views in the layout, you are overlaping your layout with other views and cant see a thing.

Comment: But then how this acitvity_main is ok ? I will edit the post with that

Comment: I can see the image buttons ... on activity_main

Comment: Your RelativeLayouts arent working properly, you should check then all

Comment: Sorry, i`m a total beginner ... can you tell me some tips on what shpuld I check ?

Comment: Try to build your layout from zero instead of copying it.